# What's os.geteuid() do?

Tags: python-2.x, raspbian

I was trying to debug [a Python 2 script](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/44404/39295) running on Raspbian (Raspberry Pi flavoured Debian Linux) which had code like

```
euid = os.geteuid()
if euid != 0:
    print("you must be root!")
    exit(1)
```

It seemed like, in the user's environment, `euid` would sometimes be nonzero even if the script was called with `sudo`.

To investigate whether this was *actually* the case, I tried to figure out what `os.geteuid()` is actually doing.

Since the `os` module is pretty OS-specific by its nature, [the source doesn't actually have a clear definition for `os.geteuid()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/os.py).

I also tried `hg clone`ing the source and compiling it, then using `inspect.findsource(os.geteuid)`, but:

```
TypeError: <built-in function geteuid> is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object
```

It's... a builtin? Then `"geteuid" in dir(__import__("__builtin__"))` should be `True`, but it isn't.

Is `geteuid`'s definition hidden because it could be spoofed into returning the wrong thing (and that would be bad)? Where can I see these sorts of functions' *actual* source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>ASCII stupid question, get a stupid ANSI.</sup>

---

I *did* try full-text searching the source, but apparently I used the wrong command the first time and gave up.

```
$ grep -rnw '.' -e "geteuid"
./Misc/setuid-prog.c:129:    uid_t euid = geteuid();
./Lib/site.py:209:    if hasattr(os, "getuid") and hasattr(os, "geteuid"):
./Lib/site.py:211:        if os.geteuid() != os.getuid():
./Lib/test/test_shutil.py:84:    @unittest.skipIf(hasattr(os, 'geteuid') and os.geteuid() == 0,
./Lib/test/test_httpservers.py:339:            if os.name == 'posix' and os.geteuid() != 0:
./Lib/test/test_httpservers.py:395:@unittest.skipIf(hasattr(os, 'geteuid') and os.geteuid() == 0,
./Lib/test/test_spwd.py:8:@unittest.skipUnless(hasattr(os, 'geteuid') and os.geteuid() == 0,
./Lib/test/test_posix.py:44:                             "getegid", "geteuid", "getgid", "getgroups",
./Lib/test/test_argparse.py:1532:@unittest.skipIf(hasattr(os, 'geteuid') and os.geteuid() == 0,
Binary file ./Lib/tarfile.py matches
./Lib/rexec.py:148:                      'getcwd', 'getuid', 'getgid', 'geteuid', 'getegid')
Binary file ./Modules/posixmodule.o matches
./Modules/posixmodule.c:4047:"geteuid() -> euid\n\n\
./Modules/posixmodule.c:4053:    return _PyInt_FromUid(geteuid());
./Modules/posixmodule.c:8944:    {"geteuid",         posix_geteuid, METH_NOARGS, posix_geteuid__doc__},
./Doc/library/rexec.rst:234:   'times', 'uname', 'getpid', 'getppid', 'getcwd', 'getuid', 'getgid', 'geteuid',
./Doc/library/os.rst:136:.. function:: geteuid()
Binary file ./python matches
Binary file ./libpython2.7.a matches
```

`./Modules/posixmodule.c:4053`, indeed:

```
#ifdef HAVE_GETEUID
PyDoc_STRVAR(posix_geteuid__doc__,
"geteuid() -> euid\n\n\
Return the current process's effective user id.");

static PyObject *
posix_geteuid(PyObject *self, PyObject *noargs)
{
    return _PyInt_FromUid(geteuid());
}
#endif
```

I don't know what I expected, `subprocess.check_output(["id"])`?

It uses the C standard library, it's never wrong.